# Total Fragments 99% and I cant get it to stay down

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, index

I have a SQL Server 2008 R2 database it is of size 13000.31 MB and my largest table has around half a million records. It is a database that I have bought. It already has indexes but when I run the database it is slow. It is slower than the database it replaced (from the same company) and should be an up grade. I have tried to rebuild the indexes as most of them are sitting at 99%. after the re-build they go to 0. but with in a few minutes they are back at 99%.

Why is this happening?

Comment: You need to give us information on what type of database it is (BI, OLTP, staging, etc), what type of workload or queries are running, etc. Have you identified any specific slow-running query? "The database is slow" is not a very good problem description.

Comment: Have you spoken to the vendor of the database?

Comment: Is index fragmentation bad? Is this really the cause of your bad performance? I suspect it is elsewhere.

Comment: I am not sure if it is the index fragmentation, it was just an easy place to start. Any other advice on whet the issue might be. the database is on the same server in the same folder stucture as the old one. The old database was around 8000 MB in size. the data inside the database is the same. but the table stucture has changed. I have asked the vernor but they have given me no help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I have tried to rebuild the indexes as most of them are sitting at 99%. after the re-build they go to 0. but with in a few minutes they are back at 99%.

I guess I know the answer here and have seen many times. Can you please check if auto shrink is on for the databases. You can use below query

```
select name,is_auto_shrink_on from sys.databases where name='db_name'
```

You must also check if there is any job running daily which is shrinking data file or may be shrinking whole database using `DBCC SHRINKDATABASE` command or may be using `DBCC SHRINKFILE` command.

Of course this could only be complete answer if you confirm whether any such activity is going on in database.

Comment: Thanks Shanky, I ran the query above, it executed successfully but there were no results. I take it take means that Auto Shink is not on? after I ran all the "Rebuild Idexes" yesterday i when to srink the database and it said it had 30%, so i shrank it but with in a few min it was back to its size before and all the indexes were 99% again. Thank you for your help

Comment: Ok, I see now Shanky, Srinking your database fragments it? whene you de-frag it makes it bigger, and takes more space, when you srink it it makes it small but fragmented. And big and defraged would in general (depending on your database) be better for performance.

Comment: Avoid shrinking please. Now did you replaced db_name with your database name it would return something of course